# Takeaway restaurant finder help in php

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I am building a takeaway finder that will find takeaways within a set distance of a uk postal code. What will happen is the user puts his/her postcode in an input box and clicks submit, the site then searches for takeaways near the user. But the catch is that this search is based on the individual takeaways delivery distance. So if a takeaway has a delivery distance of say 12 miles and the persons postcode is within 12 miles of the takeaway it will show in the results.

So far I have uk postcode database with lang and lat coordinates and also the takeaway database table holds the takeaways own postcode and its delivery distance but not the long and lat values of the takeaways postcode.

What I am asking for is not so much the code but help with the logic in how to do this.

I have the following query that will find all postcodes within a set radius of a given long and lat but Im not sure if its in miles and if it is the fastest it could be:

```
 SELECT * , 6371 * ACos( Cos( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( 56.0062 ) ) *  Cos(        RADIANS( - 3.78189 ) - RADIANS( longitude ) ) + Sin( RADIANS( latitude ) ) *    Sin( RADIANS( 56.0062 ) ) ) AS Distance
 FROM postcodes
 HAVING Distance <= '10'
 ORDER BY Distance
 LIMIT 3720 , 30
```

Comment: It's in kilometres. Change `6371` to `3963.1676` to get miles. (This is the radius of the Earth.)

Comment: Thanks that clears one issue up then.

Answer (score 0):

For performance, consider eliminating fields you don't need. The problem is you're sorting on a calculated value, so each row needs to be examined.

Ideally, you would perform additional filtering to reduce the number of rows you need. Perhaps matching prefixes of postal codes could help. You may make the observation that if the first X characters of the postal code don't match, then it must be more than 12 miles away.

If you have a lot of fields to retrieve, you can also see a big performance boost from [late row lookup](http://explainextended.com/2011/02/11/late-row-lookups-innodb/). In your case, this is particularly helpful, because you can provide a much smaller dataset for MySQL to sort.

The idea would be pull only the ID and distances for each record, sort them, and then pull the top N records (however many you need). You can then use the IDs you fetched to join back to the original table and retrieve the rest of the data. This helps because it allows MySQL to use less memory when performing the sort and if your dataset isn't in memory, you can potentially avoid some disk seeks as well depending on how big your rows are.

Comment: An alternative would be calculating a bounding box, and using those values in a WHERE clause in the SELECT statement, so the expensive calculation is only performed on a subset of data

Comment: True. Although bounding boxes are tricky with lat/long since with a fixed degree value, the physical size of the box will vary drastically as you change distance from the poles.

Comment: I think in this case it's exaccerbated by the fact that max distance isn't known until the takeaway record is read and their max free delivery retrieved, making it hard to use in a HAVING clause

Answer (score 0):

Another completely separate option. If you're focusing solely on the UK, you could consider using some type of projection into a Cartesian coordinate system. I believe [OSGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid) is probably suitable for the UK, and should give minimal error.

This opens up the possibility of using MySQL's [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html) to add an R-tree index on a series of point columns. This wouldn't give you accurate enough distances on it's own, but it would enable you to narrow down the data set to a significantly smaller portion where true distances could be efficiently calculated.

Comment: Are you focusing solely on the UK? That will dictate whether or not this approach makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You might consider [geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) as something potentially easier to implement. Doing a prefix match on a geohash can be indexed efficiently.